# Dynamically allocating memory from previously determined string length into a structure array

Tags: c

I need to create a table of different foods and their nutrition based on their weight and calories, i.e. Apple 4oz 50 calories. The array is automatically declared and the first 2 elements are explicitly initialized. I then have to loop through the remainder foods to be entered by the user based off the number i put in the macro LUNCH_QTY. Within the loop i need to store the input into a temporary character buffer, and store the weight and calories directly into the structure. Then determine the exact length of the food name and dynamically allocate the **exact amount** of memory determined from the previous step and store the pointer to it in the name member of the structure. I **CANNOT** use calloc or realloc. So i used malloc. If the dynamic allocation fails i need to output an error using stderr. And if it works i need to copy the food name into the dynamically allocated memory using memcpy. Once the for loop has completed i create the table and free the dynamically allocated memory.

My issue is, when i loop through i get hung up in the "if" statement on the last iteration. It seems to act like its looping through still but then it kicks me out of the debugger. Maybe i have pointer issues and im accessing unaccesable memory? Idk, but any help would be deeply appreciated. Im new to C so any insight would be great. Thanks in advance. Below is the code.

PS. the table is incomplete and i dont know if the table allocations would even work yet because i could not get that far yet, also i have not freed the memory yet, nor do i know if thats how its done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LUNCH_QTY 4
#define INIT_ELEM 2
#define BUFF_LENGTH 128

struct Food
{
    char *name;              //"Name" attribute of food
    int weight, calories;    //"Weight" and "Calories" attributes of food
}lunches[LUNCH_QTY] = {[0] = {"Apple", 4, 100}, [1] = {"Salad", 2, 80}};

int main()
{
    for (int StructCnt = INIT_ELEM; StructCnt < LUNCH_QTY; StructCnt++)
    {
        printf("Please input a foods name, weight, and calories all space"
               " separated: ");

        char NameBuff[BUFF_LENGTH];      //Temporary Character Buffer if this was done correctly?

        scanf("%s %d %d", NameBuff, &lunches[StructCnt].weight,
              &lunches[StructCnt].calories);
        
        //Get name length for memory allocation
        int NameLength = strlen(NameBuff);

        //Find length of food name
        int NameLength = strlen(NameBuff);

        //If dynamic allocation fails output an error
        if ((lunches[StructCnt].name = malloc(NameLength + 1)) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error - String Name Was Inputted Incorrectly");
            return(-1);
        }

        memcpy(lunches[StructCnt].name, NameBuff, sizeof(NameBuff));

    }

   


 //Print out food names, weight, and calories in order of the structure
    //and then free the memory once name is printed out
    printf("\n         LUNCH MENU"
           "\nFOOD         WEIGHT  CALORIES"
           "\n-----------------------------\n");

    int PrintCnt = 0;
    while (PrintCnt < LUNCH_QTY)
    {
        printf("%-15s %4d %4d\n", lunches[PrintCnt].name,
               lunches[PrintCnt].weight, lunches[PrintCnt].calories);
        PrintCnt++;
    }
    //Free all dynamically allocated memory
    int FreeCnt = 0;
    while (FreeCnt < LUNCH_QTY)
    {
        free(lunches[PrintCnt].name);
        PrintCnt++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(NameLength * sizeof(char))` -> `malloc((NameLength + 1) * sizeof(char))`. You need one char more for the NUL stringh terminator. This is a very commun bug we see here. BTW `malloc(NameLength + 1)` is enough, the `(char*)` cast is useless and `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. There may be other problems though

Comment: Hi @Jabberwocky i implemented what you said:                                   if ((lunches[StructCnt].name = malloc(NameLength + 1)) == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error - String Name Was Inputted Incorrectly");
            break;
        }                                                                                                                                  but im getting the same issue its hanging up on the last iteration of the for loop at that statement? any ideas?

Comment: `memcpy(lunches[StructCnt].name, NameBuff, sizeof(NameBuff));` should be `        memcpy(lunches[StructCnt].name, NameBuff, NameLength+1);`, however it would be better to replace the sequence from malloc through memcpy with `lunches[StructCnt].name = strdup(NameBuff);` or, at the very least, replace the memcy with `strcpy(lunches[StructCnt].name, NameBuff);`

Comment: @mevets that did the trick, thank you for that. And we are forced to use memcpy in this assignment.

Comment: last question for you all, how would i free the memory for all the names i used, would it be something like free(lunches->names) of the like, and would i have to loop through each name, or is there a one liner that frees all memory of names, in that structure?

Comment: So @mevets my error loop does not actually error out. If dynamic allocation fails i need to output an error message to stderr and terminate the program? However, when debugging the code i cant get it to error out. Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: @Jabberwocky how would you use free to free up memory for all elements in the array that were dynamically allocated? in this case its for the names of the food. Do you loop through each array element or is there a one liner that frees them all up?

Comment: @TIN_MAN_025 each pointer obtained via `malloc` must be freed by exactly one call to `free`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i added to the code what i have so far for freeing up dynamic memory, its at the very bottom, and i loop through each name that was allocated in the if statement above that. However, i still keep getting this error: "MEMORY DEALLOCATION ERROR: Cannot free/delete non-dynamically-allocated memory". Is there something im doing wrong that you can see when i dynamically allocate memory in the if statement? From what it says its not dynamically allocated? Its giving me a segmentation error?

Comment: @TIN_MAN_025 as much as possible, debuggers try to not interfere with the program's environment; but it is never complete.  Often running programs in debuggers makes problems go away.   Most often this is because of reliance on an uninitialized variable, either allocated from the stack or heap.  If you look through C programs, you will often find a function like `void *xmalloc(size_t n)` that checks for malloc failures and aborts the program when they occur; otherwise return the malloc value.   Another use for this is error injection; just make every n-th malloc fail, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you allocate `NameLength + 1` byte:

```
lunches[StructCnt].name = malloc(NameLength + 1));
```

But here you copy `sizeof(NameBuff)` (=128) bytes:

```
memcpy(lunches[StructCnt].name, NameBuff, sizeof(NameBuff));
```

You want this instead:

```
memcpy(lunches[StructCnt].name, NameBuff, NameLength + 1);
```

or even better:

```
strcpy(lunches[StructCnt].name, NameBuff);
```

Furthermore in the last while loop you're trying to free the first two elements of the array, although they have not been allocated dynamically via `malloc`.

You need this:

```
PrintCnt = INIT_ELEM;          // free elements 2 and 3 and leave 
                               // elements 0 and 1 alone
while (PrintCnt < LUNCH_QTY)
{
  free(lunches[PrintCnt].name);
  PrintCnt++;
}
```

Also you should use `for` loops which is more appropriate here (you've already use a for loop for the input).

```
for (int count = 0; count < LUNCH_QTY; count++)
{
  printf("%-15s %4d %4d\n", lunches[count].name,
                            lunches[count].weight, lunches[count].calories);
}

//Free all dynamically allocated memory
for (int count = INIT_ELEM; count < LUNCH_QTY; count++)
{
  free(lunches[count].name);
}
```

Be aware that your design is error prone, it's a very bad idea of having dynamically allocated memory and not dynamically allocated memory in the same array.